# How can i test async fetch function with jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, fetch

can anyone tell me how i test this function with jest

```
export function handleSubmitTest() {

  const postData = async ( url = '', data = {})=>{
        const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', 
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
       // Body data type must match "Content-Type" header        
        body: JSON.stringify(data), 
      });
  
        try {
          const newData = await response.json();
          console.log(newData);
          return newData;
        }catch(error) {
        console.log("error", error);
        }
    }
    return postData('http://localhost:8081/analyze', {text: "Picard"});
}
```

this is what i did in the test file but when i run test in the command line it gives me error that fetch is not defined.

```
import { handleSubmitTest } from '../formHandler'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';



test('55555', async () => {

    const data = await handleSubmitTest()

    expect(data).toBe({text: "Picard"});

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` is defined on the `window` scope. JSDom, the DOM implementation that Jest uses doesn't have that property in scope. You would need to [create a mock of the property you need](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom) to run tests.

That being said... if you're testing a mock, what are you really testing?

i.e. You may want to test the code that is creating, or consuming this JSON rather than native javascript features.

Answer (score -1):

For that need to write mock API.